# How do I update specific records using a comparison with linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to update records in my Orders table where the query string is equal to the customer order or `OrderNum` in the table. This is what I have tried:

```
public ActionResult Checkout(Order order)
{
    string newNum = Request.Params["unum"];
    int mynum = 0;
    bool res = int.TryParse(newNum, out mynum);

    //order = db.Orders.Single(o => mynum == o.OrderNum); - tried this first
    order = db.Orders.Single(o => o.OrderNum == mynum);
    order.RecievedShirt = false;
    order.OrderCompleted = true;
    db.SaveChanges();

    var AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Purchased","Orders");
}
```

The error that returns is **Sequence contains no elements**

**Edited**

I was able to resolve this specific issue by doing the following. Action Link on checkout button in cart:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "Checkout", new { unum = ViewBag.Data}, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "checkout-btn" })
```

Then I made the following updates to the action:

```
public ActionResult Checkout(Order order, int ? unum)
```

Then I changed the linq to reflect:

```
order = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => unum == o.OrderNum);
```

However, because this only updates the first record instead of all I cannot mark it as the answer, but wanted to mark it as progress as it did resolve the question I asked...somewhat

Comment: OrderNum is the ID of the order right?

Comment: it tells you that LINQ query returns no elements, and you expect it to have 'exact one'. You need to debug it, you're doing something wrong, wrong input value, wrong query (that field may not be set as you expect it to be), db not initialized or wrong connection etc.

Comment: `mynum` is a valid Order number ?

Comment: @Shyju yes it is!

Comment: Is `OrderNum` the primary key of the table?

Comment: @GeorgeChond yes it is

Comment: @GeorgeChond no it is not. `Id` is the primary key. `OrderNum` is passed through to the query string after being assigned to a unique session stamped with the Application User hash or `CustomerId`. When a user logs in a record is created in my logs table that includes that user id and the auto incrementing ID. The index method then matches the user up with the recorded log `Id` and `CustomerId` referenced by the query string

Comment: @GeorgeChond Should the `OrderNum` be the primary key?

Comment: @Skullomania if I understand correctly, it is unique right? You can make it the primary key instead. Can you see the record you are trying to fetch if you use the SQL Server Object Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are doing something wrong and the Order is not saved in the db.
`Sequence contains no elements` means that your Query returned nothing, so please check if it's inserted correctly first (using the SQL Server Data Explorer is an easy way).

Also, as `OrderNum` is the primary key in your table, try using [Find(key)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) (which is also faster than the `Single`) instead, like this:

```
order = db.Orders.Find(mynum);
```

Comment: George, as I was saying earlier `OrderNum` is NOT the primary key the Orders Table does contain the column `OrderNum`. You were right though, the order was saved in the DB but the query was returning blank. In order to resolve the issue I pass the query string. Then, with the query string value in the arguments of my action result I was able to perform my edit and save with one flaw. It will allow me to use single, first, or first or default. When I try to use `ToList()` visual studio complains that I cannot convert list to model. Since it is a different issue I will post it separately

Comment: Take a look at my question. I edited it so that you could see how I fixed this specific issue. I did upvote your answer as you did help me find the answer to this specific question.

Comment: Glad that it helped.